# assignment_tag TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django

I try to use assignment_tag from django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-simple-tags

Test project:

```
mysite/
manage.py
polls/
    views.py
    ...
mysite/
    ...
templates/
    polls/
        detail.html
```

In polls/views.py:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_text():
    return 'TEST TEXT'
```

Then I add code to templates/polls/detail.html

```
{% get_text as text %}
<p>The text is {{ text }}.</p>
```

But this is not work, I understand that get_text not visible, but I do not know how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template tag should not go in the `views.py` file. You need to create a module in your app's `templatetags` directory. Have a look at the [code layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) docs for template tags.

Secondly, remember to load your tag in the template before you use it, with the [`{% load %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-load) tag.

If you still have problems, update your question and include the full traceback -- 'template syntax error' isn't enough information for us to work out what's going on.